# Swift4. Toggle Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uibutton

Я делаю приложение для изучения японского для начинающих. И возникла такая ситуация, которую не могу разрешить. Мне необходимо чтобы при выборе уровня сложности могла быть активна только одна кнопка из трех по выбору(как мы обычно выбираем сложность).

Когда выбираешь азбуку, то можно чтобы две кнопки были активны или одна.

Может это просто, но я новичок и только начинаю разбираться.
Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

[image: buttons]

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:

Создаете кастомный контрол с этой кнопкой, создаете ей логическое свойство вроде `isSelected`. Добавляете коллекцию таких контролов на ваш ViewController, навешиваете действие на нажатие. При нажатии проставляете нужный статус `isSelected` тому, на который вы нажали, потом проходите по всем элементам коллекции и проверяете, что у них правильный статус. (т.к активен может быть только один)

Этот вариант довольно красиво решается через RxSwift+MVVM, но новичку наверное будет сложновато.

Вариант 2:

Используете `UISegmentedControl`.

У этого контрола априори может быть активным только один элемент, используете свойство `selectedSegmentIndex`. Пошаманите немного с визуальным отображением, будет очень похоже на то, что вы нарисовали.

Пример решения в лоб:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHiragana: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonKatagana: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEasy: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonMedium: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHard: UIButton!

    enum difficultyLevel {
        case Easy
        case Medium
        case Hard
    }

    var chosenDifficulty: difficultyLevel = .Easy;
    var isHiraganaChosen: Bool = true;
    var isKataganaChosen: Bool = true;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Стартовые значения скорее всего будут грузится откуда-то из настроек
        // Сейчас мы их захардкодим
        self.buttonEasy.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        self.buttonMedium.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        self.buttonHard.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;

        self.buttonHiragana.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        self.buttonKatagana.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
    }

    @IBAction func buttonHiraganaTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (isHiraganaChosen) {
        if (isKataganaChosen) {
            isHiraganaChosen = false;
            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: isHiraganaChosen, for: sender)
        }
        else {
            // Тут желательно как-то сообщить ползователю, что так нельзя делать
            // Можно использовать UIAlertView или что-то еще
            NSLog("Must have at least one alphabet chosen");
        }
    }
    else {
        isHiraganaChosen = true;
        self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: isHiraganaChosen, for: sender)
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonKataganaTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (isKataganaChosen) {
        if (isHiraganaChosen) {
            isKataganaChosen = false;
            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: isKataganaChosen, for: sender)
        }
        else {
            // Тут желательно как-то сообщить ползователю, что так нельзя делать
            // Можно использовать UIAlertView или что-то еще
            NSLog("Must have at least one alphabet chosen");
        }
    }
    else {
        isKataganaChosen = true;
        self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: isKataganaChosen, for: sender)
    }
}

    @IBAction func buttonEasyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Easy, and: sender);
    }

    @IBAction func buttonMediumTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Medium, and: sender)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonHardTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Hard, and: sender)
    }

    private func redrawSingleButton(isChosen: Bool, for button: UIButton) {
        if (isChosen) {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        }
        else {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        }
    }

    private func redrawDifficultyButtons(with difficulty: difficultyLevel, and button: UIButton) {
        // chosenDifficulty - сейчас старая сложность
        // difficulty - новая
        // oldButton - старая активная кнопка
        // button - новая
        let oldButton: UIButton;

        if (self.chosenDifficulty != difficulty) {
            if (self.chosenDifficulty == .Easy) {
                oldButton = buttonEasy;
            }
            else if (self.chosenDifficulty == .Medium) {
                oldButton = buttonMedium;
            }
            else {
                oldButton = buttonHard;
            }


            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: false, for: oldButton);
            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: true, for: button);
            self.chosenDifficulty = difficulty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете показать решение через RxSwift, если не трудно? Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Сегмент контрол не подходит, так как в средней части вопроса описывается вариант, при котором возможна активность сразу двух кнопок.

Comment: С помощью UISegmentedControl я смогу наверно сделать только выбор сложности. Но выбор азбуки уже нет.

Comment: Так, а какая проблема с выбором азбуки? Вам там не надо проверять состояния других выборов, это намного проще.

Comment: @IgorMokritskyi, добавил пример кода

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk, написал второй ответ с RxSwift. Я ни разу не эксперт по реактивному подходу, но вроде получится примерно так.

Comment: @Olter Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

- Можете cтилизировать [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol).
- Унаследовать от UIControl и создать свой элемент
- Добвить 3 кнопки и при нажатии на одну из них, две другие "отжимать".
- Использовать стороннюю библиотеку, подходящую под нужды

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант решения - использовать библиотеку RxSwift.

Получится примерно так:

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class ReactiveViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHiragana: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonKatagana: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEasy: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonMedium: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHard: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonNext: UIButton!

    enum difficultyLevel {
        case Easy
        case Medium
        case Hard
    }

    var chosenDifficulty: difficultyLevel = .Easy;

    // RxSwift objects
    fileprivate let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var isButtonHiraganaSelected:Variable = Variable(true)
    var isButtonKataganaSelected:Variable = Variable(true)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.buttonEasy.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        self.buttonMedium.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        self.buttonHard.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;

        self.buttonHiragana.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        self.buttonKatagana.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;

        // RxSwift bindings
        buttonHiragana.rx.tap.bind {
            if (self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value) {
                if (self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value) {
                    self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value = false;
                    self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value, for: self.buttonHiragana)
                }
                else {
                    // Тут желательно как-то сообщить ползователю, что так нельзя делать
                    // Можно использовать UIAlertView или что-то еще
                    NSLog("Must have at least one alphabet chosen");
                }
            }
            else {
                self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value = true;
                self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value, for: self.buttonHiragana)
            }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        buttonKatagana.rx.tap.bind {
            if (self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value) {
                if (self.isButtonHiraganaSelected.value) {
                    self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value = false;
                    self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value, for: self.buttonKatagana)
                }
                else {
                    // Тут желательно как-то сообщить ползователю, что так нельзя делать
                    // Можно использовать UIAlertView или что-то еще
                    NSLog("Must have at least one alphabet chosen");
                }
            }
            else {
                self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value = true;
                self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: self.isButtonKataganaSelected.value, for: self.buttonKatagana)
            }
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        buttonEasy.rx.tap.bind {
            self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Easy, and: self.buttonEasy);
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        buttonMedium.rx.tap.bind {
            self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Medium, and: self.buttonMedium);
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        buttonHard.rx.tap.bind {
            self.redrawDifficultyButtons(with: .Hard, and: self.buttonHard);
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func redrawSingleButton(isChosen: Bool, for button: UIButton) {
        if (isChosen) {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        }
        else {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        }
    }

    private func redrawDifficultyButtons(with difficulty: difficultyLevel, and button: UIButton) {
        // chosenDifficulty is old
        // difficulty is new
        let oldButton: UIButton;

        if (self.chosenDifficulty != difficulty) {
            if (self.chosenDifficulty == .Easy) {
                oldButton = buttonEasy;
            }
            else if (self.chosenDifficulty == .Medium) {
                oldButton = buttonMedium;
            }
            else {
                oldButton = buttonHard;
            }

            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: false, for: oldButton);
            self.redrawSingleButton(isChosen: true, for: button);
            self.chosenDifficulty = difficulty;
        }
    }
```

Обычно RxSwift используется вместе с архитектурным шаблоном MVVM, но мне лень выделять ViewModel. Да, еще можно ввести дополнительный Observable для перехода на следующий экран, у вас будет что-то вроде:

```
let everythingValid: Observable<Bool> = ЗамыканиеСУсловием

everythingValid
            .bind(to: buttonNextScreen.rx.isEnabled)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```